# three.js - merged geometry doesn't render update

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a merged geometry in a Mesh that has been added to the scene. I update the merged geometry in the mesh and add it to the scene. This is an an interval.

```
scene.remove(that.graph[i]);
that.graph[i].geometry.dispose();

        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          color: 0xffffff,
          vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
        });
        var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, Math.random() * 10000, 1, 1);
      var cube = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, planeMaterial);

      cube.material.color = new THREE.Color(1,0,0);

      cube.updateMatrix();
      that.graph[i].geometry.dynamic = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.merge(cube.geometry, cube.matrix);
      that.graph[i].geometry.mergeVertices();
      that.graph[i].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.morphTargetsNeedUpdate = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.tangentsNeedUpdate = true;
      that.graph[i].geometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;

      scene.add(that.graph[i]);
```

I know that most of the the update flags are not needed but I wanted to show that I added everything.

I know for sure the geometry is updated but it just does not render after the initial render.

So far the only way I could get it to render is if I add the following before the mesh is added to the scene.

```
that.graph[i].geometry = that.graph[i].geometry.clone();
```

But this causes the tab to crash after about 5 iterations.

Why is my mesh not updating with the new geometry?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `geometry.dispose()`, it removes the geometry object from the memory, so methods like `merge()` won't work anymore. Try not to merge the new geometry, but to assign it to `that.graph[i].geometry`:

```
that.graph[i].geometry.dispose();

that.graph[i].geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, Math.random() * 10000, 1, 1);

// I don't see, where you are setting up a matrix, and there is no need to create a mesh anymore
// but if you still need to apply a matrix do
that.graph[i].geometry.applyMatrix(matrix);

// if you want to change the material, e.g. you could do
that.graph[i].material.color.setRGB(1,0,0);
```

BTW: I think, `scene.remove()` and `scene.add()` are unnecessary.

I hope, it works :)